# Using poco objects with mongodb

Tags: c#, .net, spring, mongodb, poco

How to store poco c# objects using MongoDB .net driver? The custom attributes and ObjectId methods are intrusive and require changes to the domain classes introducing coupling with mongodb. Are there well documented methods to use POCO classes with MongoDB? Also any integration with SpringFramework.net.

Comment: Well you could use DTOs between your business layer and DAL, which have the required ID. But it sounds worse than creating an ID field in your objects, which isn't pretty bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation (http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.0/reference/bson/mapping/) has many examples. Anything you can do with attributes can be done via code as well.

Regarding the ObjectId, I'd suggest using a string and indicating(via code) that it should be stored as an ObjectId in the database. Alternatively, just use a Guid.